# Static IP on Kali over WiFi hotspot

Tags: wireless-networking, ip, kali-linux

I am looking for help with static a IP address on WiFi.
I have this project with Kali on a pi0w. I am using the pi-tail image as this is going to be mobile. I have the pi working great, it boots and logs in automatically. Moreover, it connects to the WiFi automatically. But my issue is, I want it to have the same IP address every time. It will connect to my iPhone's hotspot as the pi will be hidden in phone case, but I need it to have a static IP so that I can ssh to the pi headless. To do this, I need to know the IP address but can't get it (or can I?), so I figured a static IP would fix it as I will know every time when I turn it on to ssh to the same IP.

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1.** You are asking for `DHCP reservations`. iPhone's hotspot does not provide this feature. But some routers do. You can use those router instead of iPhone's hotspot where you can bind Pi's mac address to a fixed IP.

**Option 2.** You can write an script to get the IP by networking scanning. Below is the command to help you start writing it. First collect your Pi's mac address.

```
nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24 >/dev/null && arp -an | grep <mac address here> | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/[()]//g'
```

Comment: thanks. sound good. but im looking to do it on the go. so as i can turn on the pi and it will auto boot and connect to my iphone hotspot. the only issue then is trying to figure out what the ip is so i can hop on any computer, join the same hotspot and ssh into the pi(kali)